# vmware: vcenter shell command to destroy a vm

Tags: shell, vmware

Looking for a command that can be executed from vcenter server's shell to destroy a vm. 
Similar to "vmware-cmd remove vm" or "vim-cmd vmsvc/destroy vmid" but want to execute directly from vcenter's shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on vSphere 6.5, datacenter CLI (DCLI) is available.

You could do something like:

```
> dcli +i 
dcli> vcenter vm list --names xxxxxxxxx
dcli> vcenter vm delete --vm vm-xxx
```

Note: the first line takes you to the interactive DCLI shell.